# Servlet interface is not a javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, servlets

hi this bug not able to trace - help required .

I am using google app engine and writing rpc **servlet** as below

```
<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RealEstate_Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.app.realestate.navi.client.RealEstateService</servlet-class>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RealEstate_Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/real_estate/realEstateService/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**RealEstateService**

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("realEstateService")
public interface RealEstateService extends RemoteService {
ArrayList<ProjectDetails> getProjectDetails();
}

public interface RealEstateServiceAsync {
    public void getProjectDetails(AsyncCallback<ArrayList<ProjectDetails>> callback);
}
```

**RealEstateServiceImpl**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class RealEstateServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements RealEstateService{

      private static final String[] contactsFirstNameData = new String[] {
          "Hollie", "Emerson", "Healy", "Brigitte", "Elba", "Claudio",
          "Dena", "Christina", "Gail", "Orville", "Rae", "Mildred",
          "Candice", "Louise", "Emilio", "Geneva", "Heriberto", "Bulrush", 
          "Abigail", "Chad", "Terry", "Bell"};

      private final String[] contactsLastNameData = new String[] {
          "Voss", "Milton", "Colette", "Cobb", "Lockhart", "Engle",
          "Pacheco", "Blake", "Horton", "Daniel", "Childers", "Starnes",
          "Carson", "Kelchner", "Hutchinson", "Underwood", "Rush", "Bouchard", 
          "Louis", "Andrews", "English", "Snedden"};

      private final String[] contactsEmailData = new String[] {
          "mark@example.com", "hollie@example.com", "boticario@example.com",
          "emerson@example.com", "healy@example.com", "brigitte@example.com",
          "elba@example.com", "claudio@example.com", "dena@example.com",
          "brasilsp@example.com", "parker@example.com", "derbvktqsr@example.com",
          "qetlyxxogg@example.com", "antenas_sul@example.com",
          "cblake@example.com", "gailh@example.com", "orville@example.com",
          "post_master@example.com", "rchilders@example.com", "buster@example.com",
          "user31065@example.com", "ftsgeolbx@example.com"};

      private final HashMap<String, Project> projects = new HashMap<String, Project>();

      public RealEstateServiceImpl() {
        initProjects();
      }

      private void initProjects() {
        // TODO: Create a real UID for each contact
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < contactsFirstNameData.length && i < contactsLastNameData.length && i < contactsEmailData.length; ++i) {
          Project project = new Project(String.valueOf(i), contactsFirstNameData[i], contactsLastNameData[i], contactsEmailData[i]);
          projects.put(project.getId(), project); 
        }
      }

      public Project addProject(Project project) {
          project.setId(String.valueOf(projects.size()));
          projects.put(project.getId(), project); 
        return project;
      }

      public Project updateProject(Project project) {
          projects.remove(project.getId());
          projects.put(project.getId(), project); 
          return project;
      }

      public Boolean deleteProject(String id) {
          projects.remove(id);
        return true;
      }

      public ArrayList<ProjectDetails> deleteProjects(ArrayList<String> ids) {

        for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); ++i) {
            deleteProject(ids.get(i));
        }

        return getProjectDetails();
      }

      public ArrayList<ProjectDetails> getProjectDetails() {
        ArrayList<ProjectDetails> projectDetails = new ArrayList<ProjectDetails>();

        Iterator<String> it = projects.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) { 
          Project contact = projects.get(it.next());          
          projectDetails.add(contact.getLightWeightContact());
        }

        return projectDetails;
      }

      public Project getProject(String id) {
        return projects.get(id);
      }


}
```

RPC call faies with following error

```
Apr 13, 2013 4:19:02 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet interface com.app.realestate.navi.client.RealEstateService is not a javax.servlet.Servlet
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.checkServletType(ServletHolder.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:243)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:228)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$Servers.startup(DevAppServerImpl.java:451)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:198)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your web.xml mapping is wrong. You should be using RealEstateServiceImpl instead of RealEstateService

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>RealEstate_Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.app.realestate.navi.client.RealEstateServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

**Note:** In your spare time please go through basic information on GWT RPC [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC#services).