# javax.servlet.UnavailableException : GWTCommandServiceImpl is not a javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets, gwt, jetty

I work on a project and upgrade GWT version from 2.3 to 2.7 and so upgrade servlet-api from 2.4 to 3.1, spring from 3.0 to 4.3.3 and jetty from 6 to 8 or 9. and etc.
(I use maven 3.2.5 and Java 1.7.0_71 and Intellij)

```
<cglib.version>2.2</cglib.version>
<jasypt.version>1.7</jasypt.version>
<jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
<standard.taglibs.version>1.2.5</standard.taglibs.version>
<commons.io.version>2.0</commons.io.version>
<commons.logging.version>1.1.3</commons.logging.version>
<junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
<org.codehaus.groovy.version>1.8.9</org.codehaus.groovy.version>
<hibernate.version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
<hibernate.ehcache.version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate.ehcache.version>
<bonita-client.version>5.10.2</bonita-client.version>
<slf4j.version>1.7.1</slf4j.version>
<cxf.version>3.0.10</cxf.version>
<asm.version>5.0.4</asm.version>
<opensaml.version>2.6.4</opensaml.version>
<spring.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
<spring.security.cas.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.security.cas.version>
<servlet.api.version>3.1.0</servlet.api.version>
<jetty.version>9.3.12.v20160915</jetty.version>
<maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.3</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
<gwt.test.utils.version>0.47</gwt.test.utils.version>
<gwt.test.utils.gxt.version>0.46</gwt.test.utils.gxt.version>
<jaxws.maven.plugin.version>2.4.1</jaxws.maven.plugin.version>
```

Also, in gwt.xml file there are a servlet tag that worked previously:

```
<servlet path='/CommandService' class='...GWTCommandServiceImpl' />
```

when I run gwt server (DevMode), this show an exception

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class GWTCommandServiceImpl is not a javax.servlet.Servlet
```

My GWTCommandServiceImpl class:

```
public class GWTCommandServiceImpl implements GWTCommandService
```

and GWTCommandService:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("CommandService")
@WebService
public interface GWTCommandService extends RemoteService

RemoteService is com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService
```

could anyone help me?

Comment: I try these solutions but did not help me:

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710535/servlet-class-is-not-a-javax-servlet-servlet
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984229/servlet-interface-is-not-a-javax-servlet-servlet
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323138/servlet-class-com-foobar-jaxrs-application-myapplication-is-not-a-javax-servlet

Comment: I found that SelverHolder.java (`org.mortbay.jetty.servlet`) at _gwt-dev-2.3_ have not **checkServletType** method! but this is in _gwt-dev-2.7_ (`org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServerHolder`)